# Ignore Mapping all zero properties, AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, automapper

I wanna to ignore all Numeric properties with zero value in AutoMapper configuration.
So, I've written the following extension method :

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreZeroNumericProperties<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    Type sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    Type destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

    List<PropertyInfo> numericPropertis = sourceType.GetProperties().ToList();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in numericPropertis)
    {
        string sourcePropertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
        Type sourcePropertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        if (!sourcePropertyType.IsNumericType()) continue;

        bool isTheSamePropertyExistInDestinationType = destinationType.GetProperties().Any(q => q.Name == sourcePropertyName && q.PropertyType == sourcePropertyType);
        if (!isTheSamePropertyExistInDestinationType) continue;

        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "c");
        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sourcePropertyName);
        object value = Convert.ChangeType(0, sourcePropertyType);
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(value);
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(memberExpression, constantExpression), parameterExpression);
        Func<TSource, bool> func = lambdaExpression.Compile();

        expression.ForMember(sourcePropertyName, opt => opt.Condition(func));
    }
    return expression;
}
```

I'm using it as the following :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AttachmentModel, Attachment>().IgnoreZeroNumericProperties();
```

IsNumericType Method :

```
public static bool IsNumericType(this Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
    {
        case TypeCode.Byte:
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
        case TypeCode.Double:
        case TypeCode.Int16:
        case TypeCode.Int32:
        case TypeCode.Int64:
        case TypeCode.SByte:
        case TypeCode.Single:
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
            return true;
        case TypeCode.Object:
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                return IsNumericType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type));
            }
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It compiles without any problems,
But it seems doesn't work properly and all zero properties map.
What's the problem with it ?

Comment: Does it get called? Did you step through with a debugger to see what's wrong?

Comment: Yes,it does. I debugged it and it run without any issues.

Comment: If it ran without issues, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the problem.
I've corrected the following line :

```
// q.PropertyType == sourcePropertyType removed
    bool isTheSamePropertyExistInDestinationType = destinationType.GetProperties().Any(q => q.Name == sourcePropertyName);
            if (!isTheSamePropertyExistInDestinationType) continue;
```

The destination's property type was `int?` and the source's property type was `int`. So the condition didn't created.